# jQuery Navigation Change Class, but return to necessary class

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

So I am trying to make a fun and interactive navigation on my new website redesign. The overall idea is as stated. I want to mimic a URL bar, as in when you hover over different buttons on the navigation, it will change the URL in the bar.

Here is the website:
http://droddle.com/2013/

As you can see, when somebody comes to the home page, which is the blog, I want the URL bar to read, "Droddle.com/blog". When you hover over the blog icon, I want the Droddle.com part to become gray, and the /blog part to become white. I have all the images laid out in a sprite sheet.

So the overall theme is whatever page you are on, by default I want the corresponding URL to display the image of the url with the Droddle.com in white, and the /whatever in gray. Whenever you hover over a nav link, I want the url bar to display the corresponding url graphic with the droddle.com in gray and the /whatever in white. But when you mouseOut of the nav button, I want everything to return to the original state so that it can once again show the current page.

Let me know if you need more clarification

Here is my code:

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a.navlink.blog').hover(function () {
        $('div.url_text').addClass('blog').addClass('up');
    }, function () {
        $('div.url_text').removeClass('up').addClass('blog');
    });

});
```

HTML

```
    <div class="url_bar">
        <div class="url_text blog down"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
div.url_bar {
    width: 347px;
    height: 47px;
    margin: 60px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(images/url_bar.png) no-repeat center center;
    float: left;
}

    div.url_text.blog {
        width: 175px;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 14px 0 0 15px;
        padding: 0;
        background: url(images/url_bar_text.png) no-repeat;
    }

    div.url_text.blog.down {
        background-position: -16px -14px;
    }

    div.url_text.blog.up {
        background-position: -273px -14px;
    }

    div.url_text.about {
        width: 190px;
        height: 24px;
        margin: 14px 0 0 15px;
        padding: 0;
        background: url(images/url_bar_text.png) no-repeat;
    }

    div.url_text.about.down {
        background-position: -16px -49px;
    }

    div.url_text.about.up {
        background-position: -273px -49px;
    }
```

Comment: It might be easier to make your logo out of actual text and just use the `:after` pseudo-element to add the colored URL chunk.

Comment: what do you want us to do?

Comment: I want to be able to have the class change when you hover over the navigation, but when you mouseOut, I want the HTML to return to what is hardcoded on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want something like this : http://jsfiddle.net/yQ85p/

here's the code for you:

```
var defaultLogoClass = "";

$(document).ready(function(){

        defaultLogoClass = $('div.url_text').attr('class');

        $('a.navlink.blog').hover(function () {
            $('div.url_text').attr("class",'url_text blog up');
        }, function () {
            resetLogo();
        });

  $('a.navlink.about').hover(function () {
            $('div.url_text').attr("class",'url_text about up');
        }, function () {
            resetLogo();
        });

    });

function resetLogo(){
  $('div.url_text').attr("class",defaultLogoClass);
}
```

I did this for blog & about links, so you can copy paste the others.

Comment: This is perfect! But one thing. Depending on what page you are on, the resetlogo function will have to change. Let's say im on the contact page, the resect function will have to reset to the class called 'url_text contact down'

How can I incorporate that part?